# Missing become password when sudoing

Tags: ansible, sudo

I'm seeing an error message when I try to run a task with sudo in my Ansible playbook.

Here's my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: production
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: deployer
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root

  tasks:
    - name: Whoami
      command: /usr/bin/whoami
```

I would expect whoami to be `root` but the task fails with the error message:

```
» ansible-playbook -i ansible_hosts sudo.yml --ask-sudo-pass
SUDO password: [I paste my sudo password here]

PLAY [production] *************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
fatal: [MY.IP] => Missing become password

TASK: [Whoami] ****************************************************************
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

When I manually ssh into the box and try to sudo it works as expected:

```
» ssh deployer@production
» sudo whoami
[I paste the same sudo password]
root
```

The deployer user password was set by Ansible as follows (in a different playbook):

```
- hosts: production
  remote_user: root

  # The {{ansible_become_pass}} comes from this file:
  vars_files:
    - ./config.yml

  tasks:

    - name: Create deployer user
      user: name=deployer uid=1040 groups=sudo,deployer shell=/bin/bash password={{ansible_become_pass}}
```

Where `{{ansible_become_pass}}` is the password I desire hashed with the following python snippet:

```
python -c 'import crypt; print crypt.crypt("password I desire", "$1$SomeSalt$")'
```

`"password I desire"` is replace with a password and `"$1$SomeSalt$"` is a random salt.

I'm using Ansible version 1.9.4.

What's the problem?

Comment: I tried both of your playbooks and they worked for me with ansible 1.9.2.  The only change I made was to the one to set the ansible user password and I just pasted the value in rather than include it from another file.  I can't imagine that would make a difference though.  I was just using my workstation and connecting to localhost.

Comment: Maybe its a bug in your version with mixing the --ask-sudo switch with the become syntax in your playbook?  I tried both --ask-sudo and --ask-become and both worked.

Answer (score 5):

I have tried your version, and playbook, only with `--ask-pass`, which returns `"stdout": "root"` result.

You have to replace `--ask-sudo-pass` with `--ask-pass`. And make sure, your deployer user has root privileges.

```
$ ./bin/ansible --version
ansible 1.9.4
$ ./ansible/bin/ansible-playbook -vv pl.yml --ask-pass 
SSH password: 

PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************** 

TASK: [Whoami] **************************************************************** 
<localhost> REMOTE_MODULE command /usr/bin/whoami
changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["/usr/bin/whoami"], "delta": "0:00:00.002555", "end": "2015-12-05 07:17:16.634485", "rc": 0, "start": "2015-12-05 07:17:16.631930", "stderr": "", "stdout": "root", "warnings": []}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```